# Separating data from the component

Tags: angular

So I am currently trying to learn Angular 2 and I was reading the documentation and saw this found [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/displaying-data.html):

We are defining our data directly inside our component. That's fine for a demo but certainly isn't a best practice. It's not even a good practice. Although we won't do anything about that in this chapter, we'll make a mental note to fix this down the road.

My question is what is the best practice to place data? I read farther into the documentation and this wasn't really clear. My guess would be in the service of the component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic data should be loaded via services. If you have some static data you can place it in a mock file. [Here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular2-tour-of-heroes/blob/master/app/mock-heroes.ts) is an example from Tour of Heroes (you will reach the point later).